# Minikube exposed service url returns connection refused but kubectl port-forward working fine

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I did this setup to test kubernetes with minikube '[Set up Ingress on Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/)' and everything worked fine.

Then I tried to do the same with my own app and am having a problem after configuring all the steps.

The steps that I did to setup my app and kubernetes are:

- Create an app that works on port 5000
- Containarized the app in a docker image and upload to the minikube image registry
- Created a deployment for kubernetes with my container
- Run `kubectl port-forward pod/app 5000` and everyting works fine
- Created a service with type Nodeport to expose the deployment
- Run `kubectl port-forward service/app-service 5000` and everyting works fine
- Created an ingress to expose the service
- Run `curl app.info` and it returns `502 bad gateway`
- Tryied again `kubectl port-forward service/app-service 5000` and it still works fine
- Check `minikube service app-service --url` and tried the result URL and it returns `Connection refused`, the equivalent url in the demo setup that I did previously works fine so it looks like something is wrong in this step even when doing the port-forwarding works correctly.

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: echo-app
  name: app
  labels:
    app: echo
    tier: services
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: services
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: services
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: echo-api
        image: echo/api:v1.0.0b39c8f9a
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
  namespace: echo-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    tier: services
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
  namespace: echo-app
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: echo.info
      http:
        - paths:
          path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
               name: api-service
               port:
               number: 5000
```

Comment: I've got the same issue with an MLflow Tracking server deployed the same way. Did you resolved your issue ?

Comment: My problem in the end was from the app. I configured the app to listen to 'http://localhost:5000' connections but it needed to listen from 'http://*:5000' so it can accept connections from the ip assigned in the cluster. The port-forward was working because it mapped my app to the 'localhost:5000' from my machine.